# Find the moduli and argument classes for the cubic roots of $z = 1 - \cos\theta - i\sin\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

The modulus for all the cubic roots turns out to be $(2\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}))^{1/3}$.

However I'm struggling to find the argument classes for the roots. Let $r_k$ denote the k'th root.

Using trigonometry, I tried to find the argument $\phi$ for z, and then use the formula $\frac{\phi + 2\pi k}{3}$ to generate all the equivalent arguments and hence the equivalence class $[[\arg r_k]]$

So to find the argument of z, I attempted this:

$Arg(z) =\arctan{\frac{-\sin\theta}{1 - \cos\theta}} = $ ... $= arctan(\frac{-1}{\tan\frac{\theta}{2}})$

I was hoping I could get to a form where $\arctan$ neatly cancels out. I've been at this for the past hour and a half and I'm baffled. There has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $z=1-e^{i\theta}$. Then
$$z=e^{i\theta/2}(e^{-i\theta/2}-e^{i\theta/2})=-2ie^{i\theta/2}\sin(\theta/2).$$
If $\sin(\theta/2)>0$, say if $0<\theta<2\pi$, then the argument of $z$ is
$\theta/2-\pi/2$, at least up to multiples of $2\pi$. Thus the arguments of the
cube root are $(\theta-\pi)/6+2k\pi/3$.

Comment: 'then the argument of z is θ/2−π/2' could you please clarify?

Comment: $-i=e^{-\pi i/2}$. @Threnody

Answer (score 1):

To make your approach work you use the identity $$\tan\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{\tan x}\,.$$